# Atualizei Angular 5 para o 8 - Conflitos

Tags: angular

Atualizei o angular hoje e alguns conflitos apareceram... Resolvi a maioria, mas este não sei como resolver... Gostaria de ajuda para resolver.

**RequestOptionsArgs**

-> `@angular/http` não encontrou o module:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vi na documentação e agora usa-se `@angular/common/http`, então tentei:

-> `RequestOptionsArgs` não tem nenhum membro exportado: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

USADO EM:

```
protected createRequestOptions(): RequestOptionsArgs;
protected addSortRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
protected addFilterRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
protected addPagerRequestOptions(requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No **Angular v8** alguns pacotes tiveram suas funcionalidades alteradas para uma melhor performance e assim trocadas de nome, por exemplo:

- O Módulo **HttpModule** foi substituído por **HttpClientModule** sendo importado nos módulos assim => **`@angular/common/http`**
- Substitua todos os serviços **HTTP** pelo serviço **HttpClient** sendo importado assim => **`@angular/common/http`**
- Algumas Interfaces do módulo HTTP também foram modificadas como a **RequestOptionsArgs** que foi substituída por **HttpRequest**

> **1**: Para uma lista completa atualizada do que foi modificado pode ver este [link](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations).
>
> **2**: Algumas alterações não foram realizadas especificamente no Angular versão **8**, pois utilizo a versão **7** e essa versão já possui as alterações acima.